# Click on an dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, puppeteer

**Hello,**
I´m currently working on an Javascript based on Nodejs where I use Puppeteer as an help to scrape the web. As you can read in the title I´m trying to click on a dropdown menu Item, where the dropdown changes if you type in something diffrent. First here is my code:

```
// Navigate to the Homepage
    await page.goto('https://www.futbin.com/');

await page.click('#player_search');
await page.keyboard.type(playerName);
await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown');
await page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown');

// Create a screenshot
await page.screenshot({
    path: 'screenshot.png'
});
```

So Basically i do the screenshot just for proving that the headless-browser does the right thing.

The website is [futbin](https://www.futbin.com/), if you want to see how their website works and take a look at the inspect, i think that could help.

But my real problem is that normally when you press enter you directly go to the player page (where i want to get). but after my script there comes always the error "no target". So the `keyboard.press('Enter')` don´t works. Also other Suggestions from SO didn´t work for me as the dropdown isn´t native and don´t hast counting indexes.

I would really appreciate some Suggestions !

at the end i wanted leave the html code from the  first row of the dropdown as well, but i never worked so i would appreciate if you´d take a look at the website please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, you dont need to use the arrows as you can find the item to click another way. The secret is to add a `waitForSelector` as the dropdown makes a call to a api endpoint. Also notice the `waitForSelector` on the final page to render before we take the screenshot.

Therefore just do this:-

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

async function run() {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
      headless: false
  }); 

  const page = await browser.newPage(); 
  await page.goto('https://www.futbin.com/');

  await page.type('#player_search', "Dave");
  await page.waitForSelector("ul li a[data-id]");

  await page.click("ul li a[data-id]");

  await page.waitForSelector('#cal');

  await page.screenshot( { path: "./dave.png"});

  await browser.close();
}; 

run();
```

[image]

**EDIT ADDTIONAL**
To select any index use:-

```
let index = 3;
let selector = "ul li:nth-child(" + index +") a[data-id]"
await page.click(selector);
```

This goes to the third item in the dropdown. HTH

Comment: Hey there ! thank you very much ! i got it to work with my try aswell (it just neede pauses long enough to load as you said), but yours improved the time my script needs alot ! 
another question though: you saw the dropdown, how would i be able to click onto the next dropdown ? (so the second) because i want to make it variable.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: In your case I suspect you will be able to do `await page.click("ul li:nth-child(2) a[data-id]");`

Comment: once again, this comment helps me out alot but i actually meant the next child, because it won´t compile `("ul li:nth-child("+Index+") a[data-id]")`. And i have to get it to work dynamically. 
Solutions i found where putting the index into its own () and that exact thing i was trying. Error is always: Refferenece_error with index.

Comment: Hey glad I can help, to be honest if you get stuck maybe you should ask a new question as you have diverged from the original a bit (no worries though)